# ColdFusion CFQuery Looking for Month Only

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

ColdFusion 9 using Access Database stores the Dates such as 1/12/2015, 2/22/2015, 1/21/2015 etc...

I am looking to only get Month results such as January only, Feb only etc...

I can easily pull the year only If I need it using:

```
      <cfquery name="f" datasource="ds">
      select * from master
      where eventdate like '%#yr#%'
      </cfquery>
```

Where year is like 2015 - I can easily get year.

But when I switch to:

```
       where eventdate like '%1/%'
```

I get a Syntax FROM error - I can't get only January.  Likely simple solution - but I'm missing it.

Thx for any help.

Comment: What is the datatype of eventdate?

Comment: January or February of ANY year, or only for a specific year?

Comment: My Bad... Above code works - as does WHERE MONTH(eventDate) = 1 - I totally missed the where clause in my code - but put it up here...

Comment: No, only `Month()` works correctly.  Datetime columns are not stored as strings, and even if they were, the wildcard would match other strings containing a `1`, not just January.

Answer (score 2):

Use real dates, in a sane format.

yyyy-mm-dd is pretty much the only sane date format, whereas mm/dd/yyyy is pretty much the most insane date representation out there. Don't use that representation for any purpose except end user output.

```
<cfset date = Now()> <!--- or some other actual date -->
<cfset dtfrom = DateFormat(date, "yyyy-mm-01")>
<cfset dtuntil = DateFormat(DateAdd("m", 1, dtfrom), "yyyy-mm-01")>

<cfquery name="f" datasource="ds">
  select * from master
  where eventdate >= '#dtfrom#' and eventdate < '#dtuntil#'
</cfquery>
```

The advantage of using this form `>= ... and < ...` is that *if* you have an index on `eventdate`, it can be used for that. Almost every other variant of expressing the same condition (for example `Month(eventDate) = ...`) can't use an index.

Comment: Agreed. Typically the `>=` and `<` approach is best for date comparisons, though preferably using date objects and `<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" ...>` rather than strings (even Access supports it). However, one exception is if you need to retrieve all records for a specific month or day - for *any* year. In that case, the `>=` and `<` construct will not help. You must resort to using database functions like `MONTH()` or `DAY()`, which as Tomalak noted, will prevent the database from utilizing any indexes on that column, making it less efficient. So avoid them, if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

You escape special characters in access using brackets like so:

```
WHERE evendate LIKE '%1[/]%'
```

Also, if your field is an actual DATE (doesn't sound like it) you can tease it out with month() as in:

```
WHERE MONTH(eventDate) = 1
```

You might also be able to convert/cast your character field into a data using ASDATE like so:

```
WHERE MONTH(asDate(eventdate)) = 1
```

There's the limit of my ancient access experience. good luck. :)

Comment: It's important for the OP to also note a misconception they have: just because the date value displays in a certain way in a client application doesn't mean that's how it's stored internally. It'll be stored as some numeric value internally, but - as you allude to Mark - as far as Access is concerned it's probably a *date* should it should be queried *as a date*, which is why one uses date functions not string functions to extract parts of its value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Format method available in Access.

Try this: `Format([eventdate],"yyyy/mm/dd")` or if you just want the month and don't care about the year, your query could look like this:

```
select * from master
where Format([eventdate],"mm") = 1
```

Comment: Do not use Format() for date comparisons.  Format() returns a string and string comparisons of date values are notoriously ambiguous and problematic. If you absolutely must use functions, stick with date functions like `month()`, `day()`, etcetera.

Comment: Yeah I would agree with Leigh. Using date functions are waaaay better. String comparison with dates is not always correct.